# How to calculate camera sensor width?

Tags: math

I need to calculate the sensor width of a video camera. I know the angle of view and the focal length. Here is the formula as per Wikipedia :

```
angle of view = 2 x arctan(sensor width/(2xfocal length))
```

So, let's take an example :

```
70° = 2 x arctan(sensor width/7.2mm)
```

How can I calculate the sensor width?

I need this for an application that automatically calculates this information.

Thanks !

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/ ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tan` is the inverse of `arctan` [as described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

So you can do:

```
        X      = a * arctan(Y / b)
        X / a  =     arctan(Y / b)
    tan(X / a) =            Y / b
b * tan(X / a) =            Y
```

Your formula therefore becomes (with `a = 2` and `b= 2 x focal`):

```
sensor width = 2 * focal * tan(angle / 2)
```

Note that most implementations of `tan` expect angles to be expressed in radians rather than degrees. (`rad = deg * Pi / 180`, as 180 degree = Pi radians) so your example would be:

```
sensor width = 2 * 7.2 * tan(70. * Pi / 180 / 2)
```

In Python:

```
>>> 2 * 7.2 * math.tan(70. * 3.1415 / 360.)
10.082601928930876
```

Your sensor width would be `10.1mm`